# Why does my code show the NSLog but not change the label text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, label, nslog

Why does my code show the NSLog but not change the label text?
I'm trying to show the appDelegate.times but it's not working.

```
-(void)Dothis
{
    //retain
    appDelegate = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] retain];

    //display in label
    differenceLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.3f", appDelegate.times];

    //display in console
    NSLog(@"Computed time wasrggsdfgd: %@", appDelegate.times);
}
```

Comment: Your format is probably incorrect, i.e. `nil`. Try putting that in `NSLog()`.

Comment: What class is `appDelegate.times` an instance of?

Comment: Is `times` a float? I notice you are using two different `NSString` placeholders.

Comment: Is the differenceLabel object hooked up as an IBOutlet?

Comment: the NSLog works fine and returns the difference in time. but --->[differenceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", appDelegate.times]];<--- does not change the label at all and no errors occur...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this :

```
[differenceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", appDelegate.times]];
```

You really don't need to instantiate by a new NSString object by yourself for that... And moreover then you forgot to release your NSString object...

And according to your log , it seems that "appDelegate.times" is actually not a float (%f...)

Comment: `[differenceLabel setText:` and `differenceLabel.text =` will both work.

Comment: what your saying is kinda making sense but just tried the code and label is still not changing at all :/ and no errors are occurring...

Comment: @Jonathan Yeh its linked in the interface builder.

Comment: So if you do this e.g  : [differenceLabel setHidden:YES]; your label should be hidden. if you do this : [differenceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BLA BLA BAL"];  it should be displayed 'BLA BLA BLA' ... If you pass successfully through these tests, then the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: @Jonathan unfortunately my label wont hide or show the text... any suggestions?

Comment: So... the problem is not in the portion of code you posted. I bet smth is unset in IB... Wrong connexion, missing one, smth must be wrong between xCode and your IBOutlet declaration and Interface Builder... Also, try to sweep your project too... sometimes it's helps..

Comment: @Jonathan Still not sure how the NSLog works but the label won't, but I'll keep trying some things. Thanks though.

Comment: NSLog doesn't really work like an object... You cannot handle it the same way as a button or a label eg... Its behaviour is different and was designed for the specific use of logging...

Comment: <quote>You really don't need to instantiate a new NSString object for that..</quote> ?! `stringWithFormat:` instantiates a new `NSString` object just as much as alloc/init does.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

here's my function which sets the label text and it looks like this

```
-(void)seeValue
{
appdelegate = (stackoverflowQueriesAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",appdelegate.f];    
}
```

I am assigning a float value as the text of my label lbl and here's a view of the code present inside my appdelegate file

```
@interface stackoverflowQueriesAppDelegate : NSObject  {

    float f;  
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) float f;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@end
```

and here's a view to my appdelegate.m file

```
@implementation stackoverflowQueriesAppDelegate
@synthesize window=_window,f;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    f= 225.32;
    myview *obj = [[myview alloc]init];
    [self.window addSubview:obj.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

hope this helps